# "Too Many Soql queries 101"

Tags: scheduled-apex

I am getting "Too Many Soql queries 101" in my schedule class on line no 16 as the userList is giving me 320 users.How should I prevent it from happening?

```
global class MonthlyNotificationtoProfileUsers implements schedulable
{
     public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 1 * ? *';

    global static String scheduleIt() {
        MonthlyNotificationtoProfileUsers sm = new MonthlyNotificationtoProfileUsers();
        return System.schedule('Monthly Reconciliation', CRON_EXP, sm);
    }

  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
   {
      EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Id = '00X55000000E6vb'];
      List<Profile> userProfile = [select id from profile where Name='CC - User Access'];

      List<User> userList = new List<User>();

      userList = [Select id,IsActive from user where ProfileID IN:userProfile AND IsActive = TRUE];
      system.debug('userList-->'+userList);
      system.debug('userListsize-->'+userList.size());

      List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> ();

      if(userList.size() >0 && userList != Null)
      {
        for(User user : userList)
          {

                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    mail.setTargetObjectId(userList[0].Id);
                    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
                    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'lcsalesforceadmin@mcmcg.com'];
                    mails.add(mail);

          }
                    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);

      }


   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can move these queryies

`EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Id = '00X55000000E6vb'];`

`OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'lcsalesforceadmin@mcmcg.com']`;

`

on the top as a first line in `execute` method. Also hardcoding Ids is not a good idea as they tend to change when migrating changes to other environment. Also you should not query within a for loop.

Here is something that will be helpful [Apex Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)

Also in below line you should check **null** first then the **size** to prevent potential Null pointer Exceptions

`if(userList.size() >0 && userList != Null)`

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 issues :
**The 1st one comes from the un-used SQOL query that you put into a for loop.**

```
OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'lcsalesforceadmin@mcmcg.com'];
```

Remove this line an check again ?

The 2nd issue s on the `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`. You can call only 10 sendEmail methods per transaction. [check salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_email_outbound.htm)

Here is some suggestions for this sendEmail limits:

1. You can use `Messaging.MassEmailMessage` instead of `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`.
2. Process only 10 users from your userList and set the CRON_EXP to execute more often.

I agree with @manjit_singh : use a hard coded Id and name are not a best practice.
The Id can change from an org to another and the name can be changed by an administrateur.
So, you should not create a dependency with you apex code, because if the Id or Name changed, your code will break.

The query:

```
EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Id = '00X55000000E6vb'];
List<Profile> userProfile = [select id from profile where Name='CC - User Access'];
```

can be changed by :

```
EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'YOUR_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DEVELOPPER_NAME'];
List<Profile> userProfile = [select id from profile where DeveloperName = 'YOUR_PROFILE_DEVELOPPER_NAME'];
```

I hope this resolve your issue.

RedaBenh